# BluetoothA2dp get Audio session ID

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-audiomanager, a2dp

I'm using [AudioManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) for playing songs. I want to combine it with [Equalizer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Equalizer.html).

```
AudioManager manager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

int audioSessionId = manager.generateAudioSessionId();

EqualizerModel.getInstance().setEqualizer(new Equalizer(0, audioSessionId));
```

My problem is that I don't want to generate a new audio session ID, I want to get the current Audio session ID. How can I achieve it?

I saw a few examples with MediaPlayer, but I work with [BluetoothA2dp](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothA2dp.html).

Comment: Same problem here, anyone has found a way to get the current active audio session id ?